# Trying to implement VIEW_WEBSITE in a card

Tags: python, google-mirror-api

i'm trying to implement the VIEW_WEBSITE menu item but it seems no working.

This it the payload from the Playground:

"menuItems": [
    {
      "action": "VIEW_WEBSITE",
      "payload": "https://xxxx.appspot.com/mypage"
    }

This is the python code i use:

```
if 'menuItems' in self.timeline_obj:
        self.timeline_obj['menuItems'].append({'action': 'VIEW_WEBSITE', 'payload':url})
     else:
        self.timeline_obj['menuItems'] = [{'action': 'VIEW_WEBSITE', 'payload':url}]
```

and the result on the Playground is the following:

> {
>     "kind": "mirror#timelineItem",
>     "id": "b0612a88-6ffc-4542-be85-7d8d025366fb",
>     "bundleId": "wp-6-13-2-51",
>     "isBundleCover": true,
>     "created": "2013-09-06T13:02:52.931Z",
>     "updated": "2013-09-06T13:02:52.931Z",
>     "etag": "\"hzfI85yu0lKQdtWV4PO1jAbQxWw/dIvJnSSZAhq7fGkQJAO_JLjnc_8\"",
>     "text": "aa-wp-6-13-2-51",
>     "html": "\n          http://lh3.ggpht.com/mLKySisY9n2F0IqjEovLOxZ7bLp7lIO5DSQtGq7D66Klh0jcvIfrtywObJnj5QKeoHaQDgLs-wc_u558bz9W8MYy\n          \" width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\">\n          \n            Shock Advertising: Does Buzz Lead to Business?\n          \n        https://aaa-stage.appspot.com/static/images/aaa_logo.png\n        \">\n        ",
>     "menuItems": [
>       {
>         "action": "VIEW_WEBSITE",
>         "payload": "https://aa-stage.appspot.com/youtube"
>       }
>     ]
>   }

KR

Comment: that should work. Can you post a larger code sample that illustrates what isn't working, and can you indicate what it seems to be doing? Is this something you're posting via the playground?

Comment: Could you specify what is not working?

Comment: When tapping there is no action available for the user

Comment: Just tried with a simple timeline item that only has the `menuItem` and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Is your Glass running up to date software? You should have XE10 by now. Also, OPEN_URI has replaced VIEW_WEBSITE: https://developers.google.com/glass/v1/reference/timeline#menuItems.action